# How do I get rid of the blood in Hjerim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I bought the house in Windhelm, got all the upgrades, but there is all the blood on the floor and walls still. Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: Well... If you were a vampire...

Comment: Mr. Clean, Mr. Clean...

Comment: if you have already bought all upgrades and you do not have the possibility to clean the house from the steward, it's a bug, please go to [http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Bugs_(Skyrim)#Hjerim_blood_and_bones.2C_cant_get_rid_of](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Bugs_%28Skyrim%29#Hjerim_blood_and_bones.2C_cant_get_rid_of) and add a note in the bug signalation if this bug happened to you too.

Answer (score 2):

So one more quirk to that, if you want to remove the blood its a bit more complex but do able. Again, follow the first rule of the way of the voice before you do anything.

So as above, open the console (~). Click on the blood stained wall/floor and type `markfordelete`. Save in a new file, load, and the wall/floor will be missing. Reload your original save file (the one you used before you opened the console) and the wall will be back but the game won't load the quest texture, aka the blood.

It worked for me and my friend, so I hope it works for the rest of you.

-edit- So many quests later, I came back to the house and the bloody walls are back.The trick works to remove them again but it does not appear to be permanent.

Answer (score 2):

The best way, seems permanent too as far as ive seen, is to bring up the console and type in `DF429.disable`.
This permanently removed the bloodstains in the house.

Answer (score 1):

It took some work BUT I've managed to clean up most of my house (the body parts and altar) using console commands here's some help for those who want it.

FIRST CREATE A SEPARATE SAVE BEFORE DOING ANYTHING! DO NOT USE QUICKSAVE! (as quicksave is needed to do this.)

It is very possible to delete important parts of your house doing this so you want to keep a save file handy in case you remove something you didn't mean to.

Also note: this DOES NOT remove the blood stained bookshelf, chest or floor tiles. As of right now, you're stuck with them if I figure out how to replace those objects with non-bloodied versions I'll post it here.

That being said here's what you need to do:

1. walk up to the object you wish to remove
2. press ~
3. click on the object you wish to remove, it's object ID should pop up in the console window (it should say something like "000ed23d")
4. type MarkForDelete
5. Press enter
6. Press ~
7. Press F5 (quicksave)
8. Press F9 (quickload)

if done correctly the object should now be gone.

Keep in mind this is USE AT YOUR OWN RISK if you break your game I'm not going to be held responsible. This is why you need to manually create a save just in case something goes wrong you haven't lost anything. I tested deleting some items this way and then reloading from the separate save and they all came back, but if you save after you've marked an item for deletion it is gone for good.

I hope this helps some people. I didn't mind the blood so much as the altar that was blocking the bookshelf and the weapon mounts. It's also tedious work and will take a while to do but still I think some of us will be happy to get rid of the gore room.